# Bounding Box center is far away from element in Revit Python

Tags: python, revit

In Revit Python, Bounding Box center for elements like Windows, Electrical Fixtures, etc appears far away from element as it contains dimension reference witness lines, how to get Bounding box center on element not far away from it, ignoring any other reference lines?
Using below Revit Python code for BB center, which is not working for most of elements:

```py
inputBoundingBox = element.get_BoundingBox(None)
   if inputBoundingBox:
      pt = ((inputBoundingBox.Min + inputBoundingBox.Max) / 2).ToPoint()
```

Any suggestions?